# Save socket to redux toolkit? Reactjs SocketIO

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I want to save socket to state in redux toolkit but there are some errors. [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UskbQ.png)
This is socketSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    socket: {},
};

export const socketSlice = createSlice({
    name: "socket",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setSocket: (state, action) => {
            return action.payload;
        },
        disconnect: (state) => {
            state.socket = null;
        },
    },
});

export const { setSocket } = socketSlice.actions;
export default socketSlice.reducer;
```

And store.js:

```
import {
    combineReducers,
    configureStore,
    applyMiddleware,
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/index.js";
// import userReducer from "./reducers/userSlice.js";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage"; // defaults to localStorage for web
import localforage from "localforage";

const persistConfig = {
    key: "root-graduate-project",
    version: 1,
    storage: localforage,
};

// const rootReducer = combineReducers({ user: userReducer, eventReducer });
// const rootReducer = combineReducers(eventReducer);

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: [thunk],
});

let persistor = persistStore(store);

export default store;
export { persistor };
```

And dispatch in Layout.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Sidebar from "../Sidebar/Sidebar";
import Navbar from "../Navbar/Navbar";
import "./layout.scss";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setSocket } from "../../redux/reducers/socketSlice";
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
    const socket = useRef();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.user.user);
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.current = io("ws://localhost:8901");
        dispatch(setSocket(socket.current));
    }, []);
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.current.emit("addUserNotifications", currentUser.username);
    }, [currentUser, socket]);
    return (
        <div className="layout">
            <Sidebar />
            <div className="container">
                <Navbar socket={socket} />
                {children}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Layout;
```

How can I fix this? If I can't save the socket to redux, I have socket in Layout.js, how can I transmit this socket to the component Video in {children} (in children has multiple component case because I fixed Sidebar and Navbar page)